# Ignore "Display" attributes in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to acheive the DRY principle by using OOP for my view models:

```
public class ItemBase
{
    [Display(Name = "Description - Displayed in the list (so make this meaningful)")]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Optional Secondary Credential")]
    public string SecondCredential { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location - Ideally a URL")]
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Additional Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}


public class ItemDisplay : ItemBase
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
}

public class ItemEdit : ItemBase
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }

}

public class ItemAdd : Itemase
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 Parent_CategoryId { get; set; }

}
```

This does work great... however, when I want to use the ItemDisplay class to display the data in the view, it displays the Display attribute data. How would I get the view to ignore these without putting all of the members into the ItemDisplay class without the Display attrbute?

*View Code*

```
<article class="first">
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <div class="form-horizontal toppaddding">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.SecondCredential, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.SecondCredential)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.Password)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.Location)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.Notes)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you show your view markup?  I am not quite getting what you are asking

Comment: Just use different HTML helpers. For example, if you use `Html.DisplayFor` try `Html.Display`.

Comment: @DavidG - yup, that's why I wanted to see his view.  One can ignore the Display attribute by not calling the HTML helper that displays it.  :)

Comment: @Tommy Exactly my reasoning too. If binks had shown us his view I'd have made that my answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I actually thought about posting the view code... But thought it was irrelevant >_<.  Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @binks - go ahead a post the view code, we can take your example and show you how in an answer and not just comments.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question to include the view

Answer (score 0):

The `Html.LabelFor` helper first looks for the Display dataAnnotation and if there is not one, it will default to outputting the name of the property in the class.

If you do not want to use the Display data annotation in this particular view, then don't use the `Html.LabelFor` helper and instead either create your own label tag or simply output whatever you would like it to say before the `<div>` containing the model data.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-2">Alternate Description Label Text</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Raw(Model.ViewItem.Description)
            </div>
        </div>
```

In this case, you are not creating an input form, so you may think about using a span instead of a label.

Comment: I do want to use LabelFor.. or something else. I just want to ignore the [Display()] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`LabelFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833698.aspx) overload that accepts a `labelText` parameter

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ViewItem.UserName, 
               Model.ViewItem.Description, 
               htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```